# qlikview function conversion in snowflake sql

Tags: sql, qlikview

what is the meaning of intervalmatch(col a, col b) in qlikview, and how can we convert it to equivalent sql query?

I want to understand how this interval is taken in qlikview in order to convert into sql logic.
Can anyone help me to understand this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I can't help you with the SnowFlake part.

But for what `IntervalMatch` function is please have a look at [Qlik's documentation page](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/qlikview/May2023/Subsystems/Client/Content/QV_QlikView/Scripting/ScriptPrefixes/IntervalMatch.htm#).

In general `IntervalMatch` function will find (and return) the interval (user defined) in which the current value belongs. For example if we have the following defined interval:

```
Start, End
1    , 10
11   , 120
121  , 125
125  , 1000
```

And if you provide `32` then the `IntervalMatch` logic will find in which of the above intervals `32` can be found. In our case `32` will be in the interval `11 - 120`.

Hope that this helps!